# Android layout xml file not running

Tags: android, eclipse

Below is a code for layout main.xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the activity file

```
package alvisoft.helloworld;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

but when I run it on eclipse with android SDK it shows blank screen instead of showing button and textview.I am absolute beginner and don't know what's the problem Kindly Help me!

Comment: Where is your Activity, add Activity code here too

Comment: What do you mean by *"when i run it on eclipse"*? A layout file is not an executable as such and is meant to be 'inflated' at runtime usually by calling something like `setContentView(R.layout.main);` in the `onCreate(...)` method of an `Activity`.

Comment: You see blank screen in Graphical Layout in eclipse or in runtime? Sure you have <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> tag at the top?

Comment: @biegleus when  iadd it it generates an error says that "The value following version in the XML declaration must be quoted string"

Comment: I have uploaded activity file check again

Answer (score 0):

I also make mistakes like you. You can fix this error as follows:
- On the  tab Graphic_layout you drag and drop layout LinearLayout(on the left) into the interfaces.
- Then on the tab main.xml  You created newly code into this LinearLayout. This error has been fixed.

Comment: i did it in the same way by default when i start project there is a relative layout i deleted it and than drag dropped linear layout after this i drag dropped a text view than in main.xml file i changed android:text as @string/button i declared string in res/values but my problem is not yet fixed kindly help me

Answer (score 0):

i think you forgot to add your activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

update your manifest file like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="app.sample" android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

i tried your code. it is working fine. but the `R.menu.main` file was missing. i removed the options menu and tried